# Corda Whitelist not getting updated

Tags: corda, whitelist

I am using Springboot RPC webserver to run my apis. I have put java.util.Date in Whitelist still throwing error.

```
Class java.util.Date is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
```

I created a class

```
import net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist

class RequiredSerializationWhitelist : SerializationWhitelist {
    override val whitelist: List<Class<*>> = listOf(java.util.Date::class.java)
}
```

and put the file net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist in \src\main\resources\META-INF\services with following code

```
com.p2p.RequiredSerializationWhitelist
```

While deploying Nodes I get

```
No existing whitelist file found.
Calculating whitelist for current installed CorDapps..
CorDapp whitelist generated in <path>\build\nodes\whitelist.txt
Updating whitelist
Bootstrapping complete!
```

When I open my Whitelist file in the path given only my Contracts are shown. What am I missing.

Comment: Found the reason the jar was getting skipped when assembling so created the whitelist files in the root of the project

Answer (score 0):

I think there are not the same whitelist.
\build\nodes\whitelist.txt is file for Corda contract whitelist class. But your problem is net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationWhitelist that should be in JAR file under META-INF/services. Can you check that in your JAR file and this path it's contain SerializationWhitelist file?